# Custom Event Handling in GStreamer 1.0

Tags: events, event-handling, gstreamer

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around GStreamer event sending and handling. I understand the process, but can not achieve my desired outcome. I am developing a series of GStreamer plugins in tandem with a GStreamer main application. I have 3 plugins `my_src` which inherits from `GstPushSrc`, `my_transform` which inherits from `GstBaseTransform` and `my_sink` which inherits from `GstBaseSink`, and a main application `my_app`.

I am trying to send a custom event from `my_app` to all elements in the pipeline telling them to reconfigure the processing parameters. This is different from `GST_EVENT_RECONFIGURE` because it does not involve any renegotiation of caps. I am sending the event from `my_app` with the following:

```
// my_app.c

GstStructure *reconfigureStructure = gst_structure_new("reconfigure", NULL);
GstEvent *reconfigureEvent = gst_event_new_custom(GST_EVENT_CUSTOM_DOWNSTREAM, 
                                                  reconfigureStructure);
gst_element_send_event(pipeline, reconfigureEvent);
```

I have overridden the `GstBaseSrc` `event()` method as follows:

```
// my_src.c

static gboolean my_src_event(GstBaseSrc *bs, GstEvent *event);

static void
my_src_class_init(MySrcClass *msc)
{
  GstBaseSrcClass *bsc = GST_BASE_SRC_CLASS(msc);
  bsc->event = my_src_event;
}

static gboolean
my_src_event(GstBaseSrc *bs, GstEvent *event)
{
  switch (GST_EVENT_TYPE(event)) {
    case GST_EVENT_CUSTOM_DOWNSTREAM: {
      const GstStructure *structure = gst_event_get_structure(event);

      if (gst_structure_has_name(structure, "reconfigure")) {
        g_print("MY SRC RECONFIGURE\n");
        // do reconfigure things
      }

      break;
    }
  }

  return GST_BASE_SRC_CLASS(parent_class)->event(bs, event);
}
```

Similarly, I have overridden the `GstBaseSink` event handler as follows:

```
// my_sink.c

static gboolean my_sink_event(GstBaseSink *bs, GstEvent *event);

static void
my_sink_class_init(MySinkClass *msc)
{
  GstBaseSinkClass *bsc = GST_BASE_SINK_CLASS(msc);
  bsc->event = my_sink_event;
}

static gboolean
my_sink_event(GstBaseSink *bs, GstEvent *event)
{
  switch (GST_EVENT_TYPE(event)) {
    case GST_EVENT_CUSTOM_DOWNSTREAM: {
      const GstStructure *structure = gst_event_get_structure(event);

      if (gst_structure_has_name(structure, "reconfigure")) {
        g_print("MY SINK RECONFIGURE\n");
        // do reconfigure things
      }

      break;
    }
  }

  return GST_BASE_SINK_CLASS(parent_class)->event(bs, event);
}
```

Lastly, I have overridden the `GstBaseTransform` `sink_event()` method as follows:

```
// my_transform.c

static gboolean my_transform_sink_event(GstBaseTransform *bt, GstEvent *event);

static void
my_transform_class_init(MyTransformClass *mtc)
{
  GstBaseTransformClass *btc = GST_BASE_TRANDFORM_CLASS(mtc);
  btc->sink_event = my_transform_sink_event;
}

static gboolean
my_transform_sink_event(GstBaseTransfor *bt, GstEvent *event)
{
  switch (GST_EVENT_TYPE(event)) {
    case GST_EVENT_CUSTOM_DOWNSTREAM: {
      const GstStructure *structure = gst_event_get_structure(event);

      if (gst_structure_has_name(structure, "reconfigure")) {
        g_print("MY TRANSFORM RECONFIGURE\n");
        // do reconfigure things
      }

      break;
    }
  }

  return GST_BASE_TRANSFORM_CLASS(parent_class)->sink_event(bt, event);
}
```

When I run `my_app` I would expect the output to be:

```
MY SRC RECONFIGURE
MY TRANSFORM RECONFIGURE
MY SINK RECONFIGURE
```

However, I am only getting:

```
MY SINK RECONFIGURE
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: uu this is big question :) I do not have much exp.. but: I just notice that sometimes you assign to `->sink_event` sometimes just to `->event` .. and sometimes you assign to base class's ->event and sometimes to you class's event - why is that? in sink which works you assign to your class with msc->event which works.. hm not sure why

Comment: Good catch. Those were mistakes in question, but not in my actual source. These should always be assigning to the base class (ie, overriding the base class virtual functions).

Comment: The `event()` vs `sink_event()` has to do with the type of GStreamer element, from the [GstBaseSrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstBaseSrc.html), [GstBaseSink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstBaseSink.html) and [GstBaseTransform](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstBaseTransform.html) docs.

Comment: @RyanL Did you make it working ?